# Transferring saved games to PSN account

Tags: ps4, psn, ps5

I have just bought a PS5 recently and tried to transfer my PS4 saved game files to the new PS5. So I formatted the whole PS4 system to sell.

However, when I tried to transfer its saved files from my USB to the new PS5, it keep saying can not transfer because of a different account.
But I never played with a different account on my old PS4, always the same PSN account.
I looked every Youtube and stuff still no solution...

Is there any way I could find out my account detail from saved files on USB?
Or is Sony customer service able to help me out this?

Thank you guys.

Comment: Have you tried putting the USB stick into a PC? The backups are normally saved on a FAT32 volume, you might be able to open the save files in a binary file viewer and look at the contents. The PSN ID may show as a text string in one of the files.